# Oepe doesn't start on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded and installed v11.1.1.7.0 OSB successfully. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/service-bus/downloads/index.html)

After, I wanted to launch the Eclipse, but it was not started. What can I do? Is log file exist and contain the reason anywhere? I haven't determine workspace directory yet!

In advance thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: are you running it command line?

Comment: I tried this way also...

Comment: and? what was the output, also try to run java -version and tell us what you see

Comment: Same as above... Eclipse was not started, it didn't have splash screen also.